# Each HTML Table Cell Requires MYSQLQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I've designed a system were employees can punch in and out based on HTML cells they click. Basically, the data is saved in mysql database like below.

```
key employeeid timestamp punchtype
1    23        12312313    1
2    23        12312513    2
```

so on....

My HTML Table looks like below

```
EmployeeName1    firstbreaktimeout firstbreaktimein lunchtimeout lunchtimein so on....
EmployeeName2    firstbreaktimeout firstbreaktimein lunchtimeout lunchtimein so on....
EmployeeName3    firstbreaktimeout firstbreaktimein lunchtimeout lunchtimein so on....
EmployeeName4    firstbreaktimeout firstbreaktimein lunchtimeout lunchtimein so on....
```

My question refers to displaying data.

My current solution right now is each HTML table cell sends a query to get the data. It loops until all data for the date I requested is complete. It tends to lag once I have 50 employees.

Is there a better way to do this?

Check out the early version of my breaklog system.

Comment: HEre's the http://jsfiddle.net/z0rg/bWxU2/18/

Comment: Send a query for all the data, and then construct the table from this.

Comment: Yes, it's simpler to query for all the data, assign it to array, then loop through the array to display the data inside table.

Comment: If you have a query for a single cell it should be trivial to amend that to get the whole column at once. Just instead of `SELECT Time FROM table WHERE EmployeeId = XXX` use `SELECT EmployeeId, Time FROM Table`. Once you have that, look at combining those queries to retreive the entire table.